# How to modify the export function to keep formula

Tags: magento-1.9, export

I need to make a website that allow export to `.csv` with formula, so that my customer can edit that .csv file

I'm going to use PHPExcel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel as a library to do the export. I'm familiar in using this library with plain PHP and some other PHP frameworks, but not in Magento.

What I want to know is which module that I need to override (or create new one) to implement my export function? (I know that Magento has import/export function, but it only keep the data, not the formula of `.csv file`).

And because Magento has some more new concepts like Block, Template, Layouts... I don't know where to start. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure what you're going to achieve - please update your questions which data you want to export and maybe a use case for that. You don't need to include a new library for that, you can use `Varien_File_Csv` or `Varien_Io_File` + `streamWriteCsv()` which are already included in the Magento framework.

Comment: There are already some questions up here on how to learn Magento, for example: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/594/i-am-starting-out-learning-magento-with-no-php-experience-what-are-my-options/