# Magento learning Resources

Tags: module, magento-enterprise, magento-1

I am new to magento and have no concept of MVC, but i been given a job to work on it, that mean to understand it and implement the specification, now i feel too stressed as i really want to understand the magento "Beast", i have been following Tuts+ 
[Magento Fundamental](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/magento-fundamentals) and i picked up a lot. YEt everything is vague because "Hello World" isn't a cup of tea that goes into real world. I really want more in depth tutorials where i know more of breakdown e.g

1. I want to know how Model, controllers and view work together to feed data,function to given html element, how does it know how to map data to the fields.
2. How to make extra menu and link to it.
3. What is more practical way of using model, controllers, resource etc. besides just a "Hello function".
4. How do we know which method to apply or what to ask for when we say `getABC()` etc.

and many more point to make the store with a great functionality.I understand it won't be too quick to get it all down, but I am too much keen to lose my sleep over learning it and making myself proud.I am pretty new to Magento but had a fair knowledge of creating blocks, helpers, controllers etc. I am still fuzzy over example set even by Magento to make a module which just says hello world as explained in "Magento Fundamentals", I want to take a real-life approach to learning Magento e.g displaying users information like a profile, a way to update it, get products which a user order and history etc. 
How can I map my values to the right field while creation of a form?  e.g 
First name: first name
Last name: last name 
Address: address 
Etc

Where will they go in, in Blocks, or controllers? How do I make a layout to make a form? I know things like `loadLayout` and `renderLayout` that produce layout but how to use the fields in that form or layout map out to the fields I require or even display a custom menu which can perform a different action such as

> Account summary Account history Order history

Etc. Like I said I been following "Magento Fundamentals" by MagentoU and cannot seem to answer these questions.

Edit : Can it be i am don't have understanding of MVC, i follow Treehouse and Lynda for tuts, but no MVC PHP tuts over there. Only ASP.net tuts. I found this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488) for MVC but only if it is worth it?

**Update** : After exploring many links, i am still confused over why Model and controllers are used. How can we map information about a customer or a dashboard to user who has logged in, the example provided have examples like getProduct(1), how will magento know which id to look for and use and work against it. So what i mean to say is, what kind of data is stored in 
1. models,
2. controllers, 
3. I know references is use to get block already defined in xml but a practical real life example would be good.

Comment: Search mageoverflow, we have lot of resources here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/594/i-am-starting-out-learning-magento-with-no-php-experience-what-are-my-options

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt that answer is more towards designers , I am more talking about development.

Comment: Useful information can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675512/understanding-mvc) or [here](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2005/09/15/mvc_intro.html?page=1) (if you are looking for MVC in PHP)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt thank u for Alan storm link, I really learned a lot from his site. 1+ for it

Comment: @Nofel i guess going through [this](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-resources) and [this](https://github.com/aleron75/mageres) will solve your issues

Comment: @Klettseb what i don't understand is how to get data displayed in a form field

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt i realised i have learnt method XML, layout, mvc structure to some end. I am now look out for PHP to make my oop/mvc strong. any paid or unpaid content that can help me?

Comment: OOP I highly recommend Uncle Bob http://cleancoders.com/

Answer (score 8):

I also recommend my curated list of technical resources on Magento:

https://github.com/aleron75/mageres

I keep it regularly updated with the latest sources and tools, contributions are welcome.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for links, I been following [Magento for developers](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html) I cannot understand how do we map a form and plug values into the db like displaying data in fields.

Comment: I am looking for good PHP mvc / oop tutorials, i have realised the magento system is easy for me to understand but i need to make my php mvc and oop strong. Any paid or unpaid links?

Comment: I recommend Brandon Savage's books: http://www.brandonsavage.net/

Comment: great stuff, do u happen to have good references for PHP at OOP level or which would help me in Magento, be it of any level.

Answer (score 5):

This might be helpful to you, you can find a list of resources from all different areas and I´m sure you find something there

[Ben Marks Github](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-resources)

Comment: How can i ask for information, such as customer name, address, billing address and display in it a form input?

Comment: You want to build a form wehre you can gather this info?

Comment: one of many task, but this is a good starting point. I got bunch of files with php code and controllers, resource models, blocks, but i don't know where to start. So a fresh start would be good.

Comment: Another think i want to know is how things kick off when u go to a link, i know it calls a controller, but how does controller in turn know which  action and action know which model or resource model to call as i see in my file i got tons.

Comment: I think you should ask a specific question for all the things you need and not in general like this here. Example: How can i add a form and so on

Comment: this post here, has really helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, but i still recommend looking at specific issues and asking questions on this in a seperate one

Comment: I don't wanna get downvotes or blocked for asking too many question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39217/discussion-between-klettseb-and-nofel).

Answer (score 2):

It may be helpful to you to understand how admin works

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhcRRUFKhbI&index=17&list=PL3B0BAAF482B16EAB) is video tutorial link.

[here](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) is best explanation of magento by Alan Strom.

Comment: Alan Strom tuts are very good, +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of all the useful resources, including the explanations as well as the practicals from well known experts.

[Essential resources](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/18-essential-magento-resources/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best resource for beginner to understand concept with practical knowledge.

**Best Beginner Tutorial for Magento 1 and Magento 2 site:**

[Beginner Magento Tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/)

**For simple coding part of magento:**

[Basic Magento Functions](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/category/magento/)

**This is bunch of links for magento learn:
Different Blogs links for magento:**

[Magento Links](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-resources)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tutorials to learn magento. Some are for backend development and frontend development.
You can refer below sites for learning magento.

http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5

http://inchoo.net/

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/

http://code.tutsplus.com/categories/magento

and for admin area tutorial you can prefer these below sites.

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/

Comment: You can also check with inchoo.